# Looking for help with calendar notification or alert not appearing after due date/time!

Tags: macos, catalina, notifications, calendar, alert

HW: MBA 2017
OS: catalina 10.15.5

The issue I am facing is, I have several recurring events month on month basis, post due date/time these events are not showing notifications/alert or notification/alert don’t appear anymore!

For example:

Event: pay electric bill
Starts on: 25/June/2020, 16:00
Ends on: 26/June/2020, 17:00
Alert set to appear: at the time of the event
Repeat: every month 25th

Now the notification/alert for above shown event appears at the mentioned time (25/June/2020, 16:00) and stays till end time (26/June/2020, 17:00) then the notification/alert disappears! I want this to stay until I mark it as completed. How this can be done?

If I failed to open the laptop on both the days, then don’t even come to know about this event!
So how to make sure overdue events show notification at a later point of time?

Long time windows + MS outlook user and with MS Outlook, until I dismiss the event it stays. So looking for similar option with Mac calendar

Can someone suggest an option or workaround for this?

If there is a limitation with native calendar app then kindly suggest any free/paid apps which can help with this.

Comment: I recommend getting the MS Outlook App (Free) for macOS; I use it.  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm assuming you've set the Calendar notification settings to Alerts in `System preferences`, which will make event notifications stay persistent on your screen until the event either elapses, or you close/snooze the notification on screen. The only thing I can think of is, you can hold and click on `snooze` and set a reminder of the event (even if its elapsed) for 1min, 5mins, 15mins, 30mins, 1 hr, 2hrs, 1 day, 1 week later. Alternatively you can use the `Reminders` app to set tasks such as paying bills. The notifications should stay on screen even if it's overdue until it's marked complete

Comment: Thank you Allan for your quick response. I am using MS outlook but don't prefer to continue with it. As it has a different look & feel as compared to on Windows, moreover it's not fully compatible with iCloud ID (other than iCloud email it doesn't works/syncs with notes, calendar, reminders)

Comment: Hi AVelj, thank you for your quick response and clarification. all options for calendar notifications are on in system preferences...despite this said behavior to be seen. Does reminders appear even for overdue events? Thanks